# Can't find vboxdrv on Debian Testing after installing Virtualbox.

Tags: debian, virtualbox, dkms

Virtualbox refuses to load up any virtual machines, due to vboxdrv not being loaded. I have tried most things. From uninstalled everything virtualbox related, then installing linux-headers then dkms, then re-installing virtualbox and virtualbox-dkms. But to no avail. What would you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to version of VirtualBox, after the mileston it's solved, you have to use:

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Maybe you install a new kernel or virtualbox is old.

Answer (score 0):

running `modprobe vboxdrv` followed by `modprobe vboxnetflt` solved the problem for me (Debian current testing)